# php compression for images

Tags: php

I am using following code to zip images folder at once:

```
<?php
// increase script timeout value
ini_set("max_execution_time", 300);
// create object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
// open archive
if ($zip->open("my-archive.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
die ("Could not open archive");
}
// initialize an iterator
// pass it the directory to be processed
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("images"));
// iterate over the directory
// add each file found to the archive
foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
$zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}
// close and save archive
$zip->close();
echo "Archive created successfully.";
?>
```

But images are too much to compress at once. I have 70% of the images and want to zip only 30% of the images. Last image name is XYZ.jpg. So i want to zip all images after this last images. But i am not able to figure out how to do this ?

Comment: BTW, there's not much point in trying to compress JPEG or PNGs with data compression, since they have that built in.  You might consider re-encoding the JPEGs at lower quality if you want to reduce their size on disk.

Comment: What does 'after the last image' mean? 
Do you want to compress all images whose filename is lexically greater than XYZ.jpg?

Comment: I am trying to move images from my server to different one. Copying from FTP only works for half of the images as FTP is not showing all images because of large number of images

Comment: Yes, i want to compress those files only which are lexically greater than XYZ.jpg?

Comment: Then put that as a condition before you call `addFile`